# Case statement in SQl query on query

Tags: sql

I need help in forming a query on this table:

```
COUNT | Region
2   West
3   W
4   East
5   E
```

Description: 
When Region value is West, the count represents SUCCESS.When Region value is W, count represents ERROR

I want something like this:

```
Region  | Total|  Error  |  Success
West    |  5   |    3    |    2
EAST    |  9   |    5    |    4
```

The first table is an output from another query. I can write a query inside another to get this but how to I make the CASE statement work.

Comment: Don't store data like that!!!

Comment: Which db server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As @jarlh said: Don't store your data like this. Change your table design. But for the moment you could use

```
select case when region in ('West','W') then 'West'
            when region in ('East','E') then 'East'
       end as Region,
       sum(count) as total,
       sum(case when region in ('W','E') then count end) as error,
       sum(case when region not in ('W','E') then count end) as success
from your_table
group by case when region in ('West','W') then 'West'
              when region in ('East','E') then 'East'
         end
```

Comment: this gives me the count of occurrence of W and E not the sum of column count for errors and success:

COUNT  Region<br>
2 West<br>
3 W
4 East<br>
5 E<br>

Expected:
Region Total Error Success<br>
West  5 3 2<br>
EAST 9 5 4<br>

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't seem right about what you're doing, but if it is what it is then this should do the job.

```
declare @t table ([Count] int, Region varchar(32))
insert @t ([Count], Region) values (2, 'West'), (3, 'W'), (4, 'East'), (5, 'E')

select
    coalesce(t1.Region, t2.Region) as Region,
    isnull(t1.[Count], 0) + isnull(t2.[Count], 0) as Total,
    isnull(t2.[Count], 0) as Error,
    isnull(t1.[Count], 0) as Success
from
    @t t1
        full outer join @t t2 on t2.Region = left(t1.Region, 1)
where
    len(t1.Region) > 1
```

I've used a full outer join because you haven't stated that the data will always be paired up, i.e. there could be 'East' without 'E'.

Answer (score 0):

*The following feature outside Core SQL-2003 is used: F591, "Derived tables"*

```
select region,
       sum(error+success) total,
       sum(error) error,
       sum(success) success
from
(select case when char_length(Region) = 1 then count else 0 end as error,
        case when char_length(Region) > 1 then count else 0 end as success,
        case Region when 'W' then 'West'
                    when 'E' then 'East'
                    else Region end as Region
  from tablename)
group by region
```

(Untested...)